# Simplify E[E[Y|X]|Z=z] in terms of E[Y|Z=z]

Tags: conditional-expectation

Let $Y, X, Z$ be random variables. It holds that $E[E[Y|X,Z]|Z] = E[Y|Z]$. [See e.g. here Theorem 1 viii](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Etgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf)

But I am particularly interested in the expression $E[E[Y|X]|Z]$. Is there a way to relate it to $E[Y|Z]$?

I tried to follow the proof with discrete random variables but I don't know how to simplify it further:

\begin{eqnarray}
E[E[Y|X]|Z=z] & =& \sum_x E[Y | X=x] P(X=x | Z=z) \\
& = &  \sum_{y,x} y P(Y = y | X =x) P(X=x | Z=z)  \\
& = &  \sum_{y,x} y \frac{P(Y = y, X =x)}{P(X =x)} \frac{P(X =x, Z =z)}{P(Z=z)}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: In effect, you're hoping for some formula where "$X$" magically drops out.  For such a thing to exist, you *must* posit some additional information relating $X$ to $(Y,Z).$

Comment: An assumption we can make in our case is: $P(X | Z, Y) = P(X | Y)$. Not sure if this helps.